# Angular 4 scroll a div a certain amount

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a div whose height is given and it has `overflow-y: auto`, so when necessary it has a scrollbar.
Now I want to be able to scroll that div a certain amount on an event. So far I've been able to `scrollIntoView(false)` which just scrolls it to the bottom. I want to scroll it almost, but not quite to the bottom. I do not want to scroll the window, as this div is `position: fixed` relative to the window.
From what I've seen this is technically possible, but people keep referring to various plugins. Right now a plugin is not an option (maybe for some future release, but not now).

```
<form novalidate #searchFilterForm [formGroup]="filterForm" role="application">
<section id="searchFilters" role="form">
  <div class="search-filter-tab" #searchFilterTab>
    ..
  </div>
<div #searchFormContainer class="search-filter-container" >
  <div class="search-filter-header">  
    ...
  </div>
  <fieldset class="search-filter-checkboxes search-mobile-small" >
    ...
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="search-filter-sliders search-mobile-small" >
    ...
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="search-filter-dropdowns search-mobile-small" >
    ...
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset >
    <span #scrollToHere></span>
    <div class="search-filter-text-input-container search-mobile-small" *ngFor="let textItem of searchBoxList; trackBy: trackByFunc; let i = index;">

      <app-auto-complete 
              #autoCompleteBoxes
              ...
              (showToggled)="scrollToEndOfFilter($event)"
              >
          <input 
            type="text" 
            autocomplete="off"
            [attr.name]="textItem.apiName" 
            [placeholder]="textItem.label" 
            [attr.aria-label]="textItem.label"         
            class="search-filter-text-input" 
            >
      </app-auto-complete>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
</section>
</form>
```

Typescript:

```
scrollToEndOfFilter(ev){ //ev == {shown: true/false, ref: ElementRef}
    if (ev == null || (ev.shown == true && ev.ref)){
      this.searchFormContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = 950;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a dummy span inside that div and scroll into that span ?

Comment: @Vega, that's a good idea, but depending on screen height the div needs to scroll to different positions. I suppose I could go crazy with the `Renderer2` and put my span where I need it, but that has the potential to become a hot mess.

Comment: It's just the one element, but depending on screen height and other visible elements it needs to scroll differently so that a particular div (in this case an input) is visible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about standard approach:
Fist you assign a reference to your div like this:

```
<div #divToScroll></div>
```

then, you get a reference to your div:

```
@ViewChild('divToScroll') divToScroll: ElementRef;
```

and finally when you need to scroll you just call:

```
divToScroll.nativeElement.scrollTop = 30;
```

Comment: I don't know why, but that isn't working. The `el.nativeElement.scrollTop` always stays at 0.

Comment: code in question. Now that I'm going over it (again) I realize that the `overflow-y: auto` is in the div that surrounds the component in question. It may be that I need to set the `scrollTop` of that div, in the parent component....

Comment: Well, shit. That solved it. Thanks! Just need to propagate the event to the parent component and scroll there.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes tedious when we need to scroll elements( let say a particular div inside *ngFor)
best way is to get the current position and height of element using :

dynamically assign id to each div `[attr.id]=" 'section' + data.id"`

```
<div id="parentDiv" #parentDiv>
  <div *ngFor="let data of content" [attr.id]=" 'section' + data.id">
    <p>section {{data.id}}</p>
    <botton (click)="scrollMyDiv(data)"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in .ts

```
  scrollMyDiv(item) {
    let section = 'section' + item.id);
    window.scroll(0, 0);  // reset window to top 
    const elem = document.querySelector('#' + section);
    let offsetTop = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top` - x;  
    window.scroll(0, offsetTop);

  }`
```

`getBoundingClientRect().top` will give height from top. **x** is any constant value like the height of your header section.

its mostly used to provide scrollspy like feature.